# How to customize "Places" menu

Tags: 10.10, customization, places

[image]

I want to add a **Public** folder at here. -The **Public** folder exists in *~/Public* as default.
How can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open up the file manager.
2. Navigate to the folder you want to add.
3. Use Bookmarks->Add from the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Alternatively, you can navigate to the folder above the folder you want to add to the Places menu and drag and drop to the left hand pane in the file manager.

[image: Add Bookmark]

[image: Bookmark Added]

[image: Places Menu]

Comment: Oh, easy! Thanks. I can't find this feature by myself. The interface is so hided.

Answer (score 4):

In Nautilus you can simply **drag and drop** any "places" to the bottom half of the side pane (*View -> Side Pane* <kbd>F9</kbd>):

[image]

To remove entries simply select an entry and press <kbd>Del</kbd> or choose *Remove* from the right click context menu.